# Force commit input in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am looking to force the commit input in the queue dialog.

I was thinking of doing it through PowerShell. Does it get stored in a variable or something?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [a pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) `Build.SourceVersionMessage`:

> The comment of the commit or changeset for the triggering repo. We
> truncate the message to the first line or 200 characters, whichever is
> shorter. This variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an
> environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task,
> but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag. Also,
> this variable is only available on the step level and is neither
> available in the job nor stage levels (i.e. the message is not
> extracted until the job had started and checked out the code).